# Add String Variable To List (Keep Adding To List)

Tags: java, android

Question 1:

I have a function that is called every time I get a new Lat Long value, I would like to add these Lat Long values to a list but every time I get a new value the list is over written with the last value (not appended).

My code (with only latitude)

```
    public void getDistance() {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(latitudeString);

    System.out.println("list: "+list);  
}
```

Question 2:

Once I have values in the list (which will increase as values change) I would like to get the last two values everytime the list changes and perform some function (get distance between last two Lat Long values in list and so on..)

Comment: *every time I get a new value the list is over written* that is not so weird considering you remake the list every time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

a new list will be generated. You need to declare it as a private field in the class (outside the method):

```
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

If you want to do calculations though, you need to store them as `Double`s, not `String`s. That would mean your code will be something like this:

```
private List<Double> latitudes = new ArrayList<Double>();
private List<Double> longitudes = new ArrayList<Double>();

public void getDistance() {

    // get lat & lon

    Double latitude = Double.parseDouble(latitudeString);
    Double longitude = Double.parseDouble(longitudeString);

    if (latitudes.size() > 0) {
        Double lastLatitude = latitudes.get(latitudes.size() - 1);
        Double lastLongitude = longitudes.get(longitudes.size() - 1);
        // do your calculations
    }

    latitudes.add(latitude);
    longitudes.add(longitude);

}
```

Comment: Thank you, I can get old and new with:

        // do your calculations
        
        System.out.println("latitude NEW: " +latitudeString);
        System.out.println("Latitude OLD: " +latitudes.get(latitudes.size() -1));

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
public void getDistance() {
list.add(latitudeString);
System.out.println("list: "+list);  
}
```

You should instaniate your list only once in the starting.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();//declare it outside the method
public void getDistance() {
list.add(latitudeString);

System.out.println("list: "+list);  
}
```

For the second ques:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    int size = list.size();
    String[] data = new String[2];
    data[0] = list.get(size - 2);//2nd to last
    data[1] = list.get(size - 1);//last
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to declare a class member instead of creating a new local `list` everytime you call `getDistance()`. Also, since the list will store latitude and longitude information, I suggested you use `double` instead of `String`.

Move the declaration of `list` to the beginning of the class, and change the type of `list` and `latitudeString` to `double`:

```
class Class1 {
    List<double> list = new ArrayList<double>();
    ...
    public void getDistance() {
        list.add(latitudeString /*should be a double*/);
        ...
    }
}
```

Get the last two values using the get() and size() methods:

```
double value1 = list.get(list.size() - 1); //last value
double value2 = list.get(list.size() - 2); //second-to-last value
```

Answer (score -1):

1- You should instantiate your list only once in the starting.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
public void getDistance() {
list.add(latitudeString);
System.out.println("list: "+list);  
}
```

2-You will easily get last two items using list.size()-1{your last item} and list.size()-2{Your second last item}.